# How do I export hair as a 3D object?

Tags: particles, export, hair

I'm trying to make a 3D model of some hair.  I started with a basic head that I downloaded, and then I selected the section of the scalp that I wanted the hair to grow on, and separated it from the rest of the head.

Then I created the hair using particles.  Then I selected it and exported as an Object file.  But when I import it, it's just the surface of the scalp with no hair (3rd screenshot)

How can I export the particles as well?

I'm still very new to Blender, so I'm watching a TON of tutorials.  In this case I feel like i'm missing something simple.

Thanks.  I hope all is well.
Dustin

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `obj` do not support particle, why do you want to export your model? Game develop? Web 3D object? Particles usually strongly tighten with its own rendering and building system

Comment: I'm just making an instagram story filter for a friend... and I'm using this as a way to learn Blender.
Is there any other way for me to export and have the hair included?

Comment: You may need to convert the particle system to a mesh. IE Apply the particle system.

Comment: @Dontwalk when I do that it creates around 7 million vertices.. haha... so I've tried to use the Decimate modifier, to lower the number of polygons, but the modifier is only applied to the scalp that the hair has grown on, and not the actual hair.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong...